# How to Remove Style in Target when Clicked in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, target

I have a sample code that tries to color the target when I clicked its designated hyperlinks.

I am making some project and have same function on this one. When I clicked the target, I expected to color the elements that I have been linked to, and in the code it is working, but I'd like to remove the color of the target when I clicked again anywhere else in the screen.

```css
p:target {
  background-color: gold;
}

/* Add a pseudo-element inside the target element */
p:target::before {
  font: 70% sans-serif;
  content: "►";
  color: limegreen;
  margin-right: 0.25em;
}

/* Style italic elements within the target element */
p:target i {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h3>Table of Contents</h3>
<ol>
  <li><a href="#p1">Jump to the first paragraph!</a></li>
  <li><a href="#p2">Jump to the second paragraph!</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#nowhere">
      This link goes nowhere, because the target doesn't exist.
    </a>
  </li>
</ol>
<h3>My Fun Article</h3>
<p id="p1">
  You can target <i>this paragraph</i> using a URL fragment. Click on the link above to try out!
</p>
<p id="p2">
  This is <i>another paragraph</i>, also accessible from the links above. Isn't that delightful?
</p>
```

I'd like to remove the color of the target when I clicked anywhere in the screen. How should I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need a little bit of Javascript here:

```js
// Get the target element that you want to remove the color from
const target = document.querySelector('#my-target');

// Add a click event listener to the entire document
document.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // When the document is clicked, remove the color from the target element
    target.style.color = '';
});
```